# Convert filepath string to python import string

Tags: python

I would like to convertos file paths like `'./foo/bar/file.py'` to paths used in python import like `'foo.bar.file'`.

I could very easily code my self these functions, but I wanted to know if there is a function for making that?

It would be great also if the functions works for windows and linux file paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```py
import pathlib

path = pathlib.Path('foo/bar/file.py')
formatted_path = '.'.join(path.with_suffix('').parts)

# And do what you want with formatted_path
```